# Remove a part of Hexa Message in order to have a good message

Tags: java, xml, string, del

I tried to convert a String of Hex chars to a String using this method:

```
public String HexToString(String inputString){
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i+=2) {
        String str = inputString.substring(i, i+2);
        output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Input is:

> "4d442020000000020000000000000008ffffffff000000000000022200‌​0001b54d514852463220‌​20000000000000000141‌​4d5120434d504c4c3333‌​2020202020d75db05811‌​51d02000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​00202020202020202020‌​20202020202020202020‌​20202020202020202020‌​20202020202020202020‌​20202020202020202043‌​4d504c4c333320202020‌​20202020202020202020‌​20000000000000000000‌​00000000020202020202‌​02020202020202020202‌​02020202020202020202‌​02020202020200000001‌​c7765626c6f6...."

This method works, but the problem that my message contains strange chars. 
After converting I received in the header this characters: "µMQHRF2"

The question is how could i delete this header ? Should i do it when the message is on Hexa or after converting ? and how can i delete this characters from my string ?

Comment: how your input look like? and what you expect to get?

Comment: My input is an hexa it like ("4d442020000000020000000000000008ffffffff0000000000000222000001b54d514852463220200000000000000001414d5120434d504c4c33332020202020d75db0581151d02000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020434d504c4c333320202020202020202020202020202000000000000000000000000000020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000001c7765626c6f6....") when i convert i recived those strong caracterers at the beging that i want to remove

Comment: Converting "4d44" using your method outputs in "MD", so what do you mean by "µMQHRF2" in the header?

Comment: Your input example contains invisible unicode characters like in this snippet: http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer/?q=200%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B00 - you should get rid of those.

Comment: Furthermore, when you decode a clean version (`4d442020000000020000000000000008ffffffff0000000000000222000001b54d514852463220200000000000000001414d5120434d504c4c33332020202020d75db0581151d02000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020434d504c4c333320202020202020202020202020202000000000000000000000000000020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000001c7765626c6f6`), what you get as string is not a string but clearly from a binary protocol (from some Message Queue)

Comment: I fixed parts of the wrong spelling (HINT: doesn't your browswer do SPELL checking?!) and added your example data. But you should still look into this question to further improve the wording; I wasn't able to really understand what you are saying. Same will be for any other readers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an apache commons library. Here is the link

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

Comment: It not my objectif ! I want to delete firs carcters from the message ! for exemaple the message is "xcds& é&&é &é"é& this is example" i want to remove this "xcds& é&&é &é"é&" and the message would be " this is example"